# How to bind a dependency object inside a wpf datagrid to a observable collection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid, dependency-properties

**Background:**
I have a wpf datagrid that has a custom class (`CustomTextBox`) that inherits from a `TextBox`. I have created a dependency object (`ValueProperty`) in this custom class so I can bind to it. I also have a observable collection that I use as a `DataSource` for the `DataGrid`.

**Issue:**
The problem is that when I bind my dependency property of my custom class to a public property in the observable collection, nothing is showing in the `DataGrid`.

Here is the *xaml* for the `DataGrid` `TemplateColumn` where the binding happens:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Drawing Location"  Width="240" CellStyle="{StaticResource dataGridCellStyle}">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="Drawing Location" Width="230" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CustomTextBox:CustomTextBox x:Name="ftbDrawingX" Value="{Binding DrawingLocationX, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                             Style="{StaticResource textBox}" Width="85" Behavior="DistanceCombinedFtIn"/>
                <Label Content=","/>
                <CustomTextBox:CustomTextBox x:Name="ftbDrawingY" Value="{Binding DrawingLocationY, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                             Style="{StaticResource textBox}" Width="85" Behavior="DistanceCombinedFtIn"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

And here is my dependency property in the custom class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(CustomTextBox), 
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0D, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, new PropertyChangedCallback(ValueProperty_OnTextPropertyChanged)));

public double Value
{
    get {return (double)this.GetValue(ValueProperty);}    
    set
    {

    }
}
```

In the code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<CustomItem> data = new ObservableCollection<CustomItem>();    
this.dgTakeoffDataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
```

The `CustomItem` object implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has two properties: `DrawingLocationX` and `DrawingLocationY`.

Can anyone please take a look and tell me what I have done wrong. My `DataGrid` comes up empty, I know my issue is with binding to a dependency object. Any help is appreciated here.

**EDIT:**
I removed all logic from the setter property of Value, and I have added a callback method which handles the changes to the dependency object, and also updates it's Text property.

```
private static void ValueProperty_OnTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        CustomTextBox box = d as CustomTextBox;
        if (box != null)
        {
            box.value = Conversions.RoundLeastSignificant(Conversions.RoundLeastSignificant((double)eventArgs.NewValue));
            box.Text = Conversions.FormatReadTextValue((double)eventArgs.NewValue, box.behavior, box.acadDocument);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where do you expect the DrawingLocationX property to get displayed? In the TextBox? How is your "textBox" style defined?

Comment: @mm8 I expect the DrawingLocationX and DrawingLocationY to be displayed in the CustomTextBox controls. If you look in the Xaml, I am binding to those two. The Style just sets sizing, background color and placeholder text.

Comment: So why are you expecting a TextBox to be able to display your the value of your custom property...? Where do you set the Text property?

Comment: I have made some changes to the code, see the edits. I am now able to get values to display, but not all of them are displaying, which is rather bizarre.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to resolve this issue. The solution is in my last comment:
The solution being to remove all the logic from the setter of the property, and handle setting Value in a CallBack method defined when you register the dependency property.

This is the general solution. Hope it helps others as well.